# Tabbed content not showing default content and not adding class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a tabbed module, which for now has three tabs.

**How it works**: User clicks on a `carousel_element` and it displays `carousel_hidden-text` within that div to another div called `carousel_quote`.

I'm unsure on why:

1. The default content isn't already pre-loaded in `carousel_quote`. I.e. In the demo below, you can see the red box is empty. I want it to, by default, display the second `carousel_element` (lorum ipsum 2).
2. Again, by default, I want the border on the second `carousel_element` to show red (so it indicates this tab is active). To do this, I have `jQuery('."carousel_element:nth-child(2)').addClass("carousel_selected");` but it doesn't seem to be doing anything? Of course, if any other tab is clicked, I want to remove `carousel_selected` from there and add it to the appropriate `carousel_element`.

**Code**:

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.carousel_element', function() {
  jQuery('.carousel_quote').html(jQuery(this).find('.carousel_hidden-text').html());
  jQuery('."carousel_element:nth-child(2)').addClass("carousel_selected");
  jQuery('.carousel_element').removeClass('carousel_selected');
  jQuery(this).addClass('carousel_selected');
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  color: #002f33;
  width: 100vw;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.carousel_element {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
  height: 6em;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel_element .carousel_hidden-text {
  /* display: none; */
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel_container .carousel_quote {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 10em;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.carousel_selected {
  border-color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container carousel_container">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="carousel_element">
        <div class="carousel_hidden-text">
          <p>Lorum Ipsum 1 </p>
          <p class="carousel_reference">Author1 </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel_element">
        <div class="carousel_hidden-text">
          <p>Lorum Ipsum 2</p>
          <p class="carousel_reference">Author 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel_element">
        <div class="carousel_hidden-text">
          <p>Lorum Ipsum 3</p>
          <p class="carousel_reference">Author 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .carousel end -->
    <div class="carousel_quote"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for on load add this function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.carousel_element:nth-child(2)').addClass("carousel_selected");
   $('.carousel_quote').html($('.carousel_element:nth-child(2)').find('.carousel_hidden-text').html());
});
```

try the below solution it will works

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.carousel_element:nth-child(2)').addClass("carousel_selected");
   $('.carousel_quote').html($('.carousel_element:nth-child(2)').find('.carousel_hidden-text').html());
   
$('.carousel_element').click(function() {
  $('.carousel_quote').html($(this).find('.carousel_hidden-text').html());
 
  //$('.carousel_element').removeClass('carousel_selected');
$(this).addClass("carousel_selected").siblings().removeClass("carousel_selected");

});
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  color: #002f33;
  width: 100vw;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.carousel_element {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
  height: 6em;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel_element .carousel_hidden-text {
  /* display: none; */
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel_container .carousel_quote {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 10em;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.carousel_selected {
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container carousel_container">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="carousel_element">
        <div class="carousel_hidden-text">
          <p>Lorum Ipsum 1 </p>
          <p class="carousel_reference">Author1 </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel_element">
        <div class="carousel_hidden-text">
          <p>Lorum Ipsum 2</p>
          <p class="carousel_reference">Author 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel_element">
        <div class="carousel_hidden-text">
          <p>Lorum Ipsum 3</p>
          <p class="carousel_reference">Author 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .carousel end -->
    <div class="carousel_quote"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```